# Can an eigen vector of a Pseudo-Hermitian operator with a real eigen value have a vanishing norm and do they form a basis of the Hilbert space?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We consider a Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$ and a linear, diagonalizable operator $A : \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ such that $A ^{\dagger} = \eta A \eta ^{-1}$ with $\eta$ an hermitian, bounded and invertible operator which is everywhere defined but not positive-definite. $(\cdot, \eta \cdot)$ define a semi norm and $A$ is (pseudo-)hermitian for this semi norm.

We can find defined a set of eigen vectors  $\Psi_n$ of $A$ with eigen values $\{ a_n \}$. There are real eigen values and complex eigen values. The complex eigen values come in complex conjugate pairs. If  $n \neq m$ then $(\Psi_m, \eta \Psi_n) = 0 $ except if $a_n$ and $a_m$ are complex conjugate (and supposing they are non-degenerate for the sake of simplicity). In addition, $(\Psi_k, \eta \Psi_k) = 0 $ if $a_k$ is complex.

Can  $(\Psi_k, \eta \Psi_k) = 0 $ even if  $a_k$ is real. There is nothing that stop this from happening in my opinion. Since the only constraint I can think of is $(a_i ^* - a_j) (\Psi_i, \eta \Psi_j) = 0 $